# aks network policy not working with azure network plugin

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I was just trying out the tutorial under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-network-policies in an azure subscription

But the network policies are not working. To be precise, blocking of ingress itself doesn't work. It looks like network policy settings are having zero effect in aks. I tried with a different aks cluster with azure CNI and same problem.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Share the YAML file you use to create the network policy, it's the necessary message.

Comment: verbātim from the tutorial (even same variable names)

Comment: Do you follow the steps to create the AKS cluster without a difference?

Comment: yes, copy paste (only difference was region setting -- germany instead of canada)

Comment: If you use the azure network-policy, then it should be no problem. Maybe you can check the role assignment that you assign to the service principal of AKS.